# Rails_admin, change datetime filters format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Currently on rails_admin, when user wants to filter by datetime, it shows selected date in this format:

[image: img]

However, it does not filter by date if its language is different than english.

How to change format of datetime in filters?